# variable scope for require

Tags: javascript, scope, arguments, require

I have a limited JS interpreter for a mobile app, which does not allow usage of `module.export`. It has some custom global variables, say, `customProp` which are available at runtime, in the interpreter, in the app.

For my tests though I still need to require such JS files and define such variables. Is there a way to pass a mocked value to such custom variables during tests, when call them using `require`? A straightforward way would be just to add such variables to the global scope, but with many tests it becomes unusable and very error prone.

A typical script `script.js`:

```
customProp.customFuncCall(); // This works in the engine
```

A test `test.js`:

```
const { script } = require("./script"); // <- This throws an error: customProp is undefined
```

I see it is possible to pass a variable to a module when require it, but in that case, the module has to have
`module.exports = function (passedVariable) {}` which I cannot do.

Comment: Does the "limited JS Interpreter" have a name? As in is it open source with source code available, or documented anywhere?

Comment: It might be better to say, that the app doesn't allow it. I don't know why. The interpreter must be something widely available, nothing unusual. But the fact is, that it is not allowed to use module.exports in the JS source code.

Comment: Maybe you should write a custom `require` function using `eval` - or look one up? Hard to say with so little information on which to base guesses :-)